# How to implement Python imports that work for testing and production?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have a Python project which is structured as follows:

```bash
root/
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── LICENCE
├── .gitignore
└── src/
    └── package_name/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── cli/
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── synthesizers/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── models.py
```

It's is supposed to become a Python package with two main submodules: `cli` and `synthesizers`. The cli submodule requires certain imports from the synthesizers submodule. Currently these imports are listed as follows:

```py
from ..synthesizers.models import CTGAN, DPCTGAN
```

This relative import does work after packaging the project and installing it via pip. Unfortunately, this does not work if I run `__init__.py` in the cli submodule separately, Python raises the following error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

I have taken a look at popular Python packages to see how they do it, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it right.

What are common ways to implement imports that work for both development and production purposes. In other words: how should imports be implemented so one can continue development and testing on separate submodules, while the imports are also valid in a package?

Comment: How exactly do you "run `__init__.py` in the cli submodule separately"?

Comment: The error means that you are trying to execute a file which contains relative imports as a script. In a script, you can only use absolute imports.

Comment: I am out of close votes for today, but this is a duplicate of [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with `__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764). The short version is that the problem is **how** you "run `__init__.py` in the cli submodule separately", and fixing this does not actually require changing the code. However, the canonicals for `import` in Python are a mess, because most of the popular content was written many years ago and is full of cargo-cult nonsense.

Comment: If I'm in the root folder and run `src/package_name/cli/__init__.py` Python returns the error message. I have tried to change the import to something like `from package_name.synthesizers import models`, but then Python raises a ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: (For example, the reason why that duplicate has the title it does, and is asked in the specific way it is, is because of old misconceptions about the role of `__init__.py` in creating packages. It has not been *necessary* for making relative imports work since Python 3.3, but OP thought that it was and then didn't understand why "even that isn't enough", so to speak. But in reality, "namespace packages" that lack `__init__.py` work just fine.)

Comment: "If I'm in the root folder and run src/package_name/cli/__init__.py Python returns the error message." Yes. You should either be in the src folder (or else *install the package* - perhaps with `pip install -e .` - or use `PYTHONPATH`, so that this folder will be put on the `sys.path` ahead of time) and run `python -m package_name.cli` (notice, a package name, not a file name); or else set up a driver script. The linked duplicate explains all of this in detail, along with giving a very comprehensive explanation of why.

Comment: "I have tried to change the import to (an absolute import), but then Python raises a ModuleNotFoundError." Yes. That comes from the attempt to import `package_name`; packages **are modules themselves** in Python, represented with the same class (not even a subclass). It isn't found because `src` isn't on your `sys.path`. This is probably also covered by the existing Q&A I offered.

Comment: I always recommend against making modifications to `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`, there is almost always a better, cleaner solution. I wish we stopped mentioning these as a potential solution, in my experience they almost never are a good solution (a temporary hack at best). Here the solution is to make sure the project is correctly installed (as editable or not). -- Also always use the `python -m` way of running code that is part of an importable package. If the directory contains an `__init__.py` it is an import package, and executables inside it should be run with `python -m`.